# Searching and editing elements in the ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my problem.

I create an array list:

```
ArrayList <account> list = new ArrayList<account>();
```

I add an account:

```
account studentAccount = new account(employeeId(), employeeName(), employeeEmail(), 0);
```

Now I am trying to change employee's email where employee's id is equal 000001.
I tried using indexOf, but that returned -1 at all times. 
Could someone please explain how to search and edit elements in this kind of arrayList. I have came across multiple tutorials, but they are all talking about arrayLists where every slot is talking either by one int or one character etc.

Comment: Side note: code to interfaces by instantiating list as: List<Account> list = new ArrayList<Account>();

Comment: Also if on java 7+ you can use the diamond operator <>

Comment: anothert side not : Use Pascal case for class name

Comment: What @Ricky said is known as Dependency Inversion. In case you want a bit more context check out the SOLID principles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can foreach over the Arraylist to find the employee with id 1:

```
for (account a : list) {
    if (a.getEmployeeId().equals("000001")
        a.setEmail("foobar");
}
```

I'm missing some information to give a more specific answer (type of id, getter and setter for id/email)

Comment: I tried your way and it returns positive even if ArrayList is empty. But then I realise that I am using getEmployeeId() for both getting text out of textfield and getting Id from account class. I changed one of them and your method works absolutely fine!

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf` relies on you overriding `hashCode` and `equals` in your `account` class to work correctly.

However, these two methods should take into account all (immutable) properties of `account` to calculate their return value (i.e. employee id, name, email etc). If you are simply looking for an instance with a given account number, you will need to perform a search through all elements, as proposed by @ParkerHalo.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Java 8 you can use lambda expressions / stream API:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getEmployeeId().equals("001"))
    .forEach(x -> x.setEmail("ab@c.de"));
```

This changes the email-adress for each account with the given id - ideally, `filter` will only return one account of course (or none, which is fine for `forEach`). If you chance your filter expression and filter for something that returns more accounts, `forEach` will work fine aswell of course.

Answer (score 1):

Under java 8+, you can also use the java stream API :

```
// First find the element
Optional<Account> account = list.stream( )
    .filter( a -> a.getEmployeeId().equals("0000001") )
    .findAny();

// if found, set the email
if ( account.isPresent( ) )
    account.get( ).setEmail( "newEmail");
```